# LWUIT bitmap font

Tags: java-me, lwuit, font-size, lwuit-resource-editor, bitmap-fonts

I'm Developing a small application in one of the classes i'm using two buttons , I have used bitmap fonts for all the components used in application (using Resource Editor) for both English and Persian language. Now I want in result of clicking button "small font" size of all component's fonts become smaller and in result of clicking button "large font" fonts get updated to larger size.
how can I do this , I mean how can I change size of bitmap font dynamically.
thanks for your support in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the "pressed" style of the button to the desired font.